# ios: storyboard + tabbar + more button (design)

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have a little app that shows a list of dvds, then you can drill down from the table view and get some details.  It also has a tab bar at the bottom and you can switch from dvds to bluray as tab buttons.  This all works fine.

In reading about tab bar apps, I saw a demo that once you added more than 5 tab bar buttons, "more" would show up and then you can drag-n-drop the buttons like in Apple's Music app, which is cool!  I also noticed that each tab bar button controlled a separate navigation controller, which was a new technique to me.

When I created my app, it had a single navigation controller and I added a view controller with the top of the view being a table view and the bottom of the view a tab bar.  I then drag buttons to the button bar and can add more than 5 buttons and "more" doesn't show up.

So, I figure, it needs to to be a different navigation controller design.

I am confused on if I can take my app and embed a tab view controller or if I can adapt what I have or not.

Right now, since all tabs are basically the same (a table that drills down to a detail view) I just reload the data from a different file when the tab is switched.  Nice and clean.

If I switched to the tab view controller concept, it seems wasteful to create 5 navigation controllers with 5 table views that drill down to 5 detail views.  Plus what if I wanted 7? or 9?  (I do realize (or guess) that I can give each 5 views the same class name, but still the UI has lots of storyboards…)

This is a design question to better understand what my options are.

Comment: It sounds like you just added a tabBar to your navigation controller -- that's not the same thing as a TabBarController, so that's why you didn't get the "more" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab bar controller must always be the root controller of an application.  (Unless it's in a split view, in which case the different sides of the split can be a tab bar controller - but it still has to be the root.)

So, the correct design for your app is: tab bar controller as root, each tab containing a navigation controller, each navigation controller having your table view controller as the first view controller.  It may seem wasteful but if you think about it, each tab really needs to have its own stack of controllers, so there's no other reasonable way to do it.  If user on tab 1 is 2 deep in a nav stack but tab 2 is 7 deep you don't want to switch between tabs and lose your place.

Comment: Thanks, interesting point.  On the table view drill-down, I segued to another tableview or the detailview and those didn't have the tab bar, because I was concerned about how to do that.  Good to know that is a good reason for tab bar controller.